# tar local folder and transfer sensitive data to remote machine vs rsync

Tags: ssh, rhel, rsync, tar, scp

I need to backup some important data from local folder and transfer it to remote machine - worker01

so I think to tar the local folder and send the tar to remote machine as the following

```
tar zcvf - /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current | ssh root@worker01 "cat > /home/master01.journal.tar.gz"
```

but other approach can be also with rsync as

```
mkdir -p /home/bck_master01.journal ( on remote machine ) 
rsync -a /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current  root@worker01:/home/bck_master01.journal
```

so because we are dealing with very sensitive data , I am wondering what is the preferred approach?

Comment: Check out [duplicity](https://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) and its gui `deja-dup`.

Comment: If you don't trust ssh, then who can you trust?

Answer (score 0):

Real backup sw with encryption, see borg, restic or "enterprise" bareos/bacula, all allow encryption, not only of transfer but of the data itself.